# How to create numeric columns with bars in table

Tags: tables, tcolorbox, bar-chart

I wonder how could the following columns be created in (La)TeX for a table that has fixed/known column widths. I've been tinkering with [tcolorbox](https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) but I couldn't find a way to make the text lay over the coloured box (rather than inside).

[image: Columns with numeric bar]

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look for [`pgfplots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) or `pgfplotstable` (also in pgfplots) packages but if you prefer to do it by hand, this could be a starting point:

```
\documentclass[]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

% #1 - column width (3cm by default)
% #2 - value to be shown
% #3 - maximum value in column
\newcommand{\mybar}[3][3cm]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[minimum width=#1] (top) {#2};
\node[draw=green!80!black, fill=green!30, minimum width={(#2/#3)*#1}, below right=0pt of top.south west] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\mybar{0.54040399}{0.605198872} & \mybar{0.33004729}{0.33004729} \\
\mybar{0.53584356}{0.605198872} & \mybar{0.31441314}{0.33004729} \\
\mybar{0.30299224}{0.605198872} & \mybar{0.24153336}{0.33004729} \\
\mybar{0.605198872}{0.605198872} & \mybar{0.22097618}{0.33004729}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ignasi, I will look into these packages indeed (or leverage your solution).